# Write several values in one string

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to both VBA and stackoverflow. So please be patient ;).

I searched for a solution but could not find it.
My problem is as follows:

I have a column (A) with names and then a column (B) where some cells contain an "X" and others do not. I want to know which names have an "X" besides them.

Example:
[image]

**I want now a string as a result, in one cell.** 
In this example:

```
Noah;Jacob;Elijah;Jayden
```

I got not very far.

```
For r = 1 To 20
    If Cells(r, 2) = "X" Then A = Cells(r, 1) Else
Next
```

Then "A" is "Noah" and I can write it in a cell, but I want it to find all values and then write them combined, preferable seperated by ; in a cell.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Create a string variable, then append your results to that variable based on "X" being in column B. Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim i         As Integer
Dim result    As String

For i = 1 To 20
    If UCase(Cells(i, 2).Value) = "X" Then
        result = result & Cells(i, 1).Value & ";"
    End If
Next

'// output the result to C1
Range("C1").Value = Left$(result, Len(result) - 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel's native worksheet formulas do not handle concatenating an unknown number of strings  together and compensating for the maximum number possible can get messy. A User Defined Function¹ (aka UDF) takes advantage of VBA's ability to process loops through a large number of rows while making numerical or string comparisons 'on-the-fly'.

**[build_List UDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOqZ.png)**

```
Function build_List(rNAMs As Range, rEXs As Range, vEX As Variant, _
                        Optional delim As String = ";", _
                        Optional bCS As Boolean = False)
    Dim str As String, rw As Long, cl As Long

    With rNAMs.Parent
        Set rNAMs = Intersect(.UsedRange, rNAMs)
        Set rEXs = .Cells(rEXs.Rows(1).Row, rEXs.Columns(1).Column). _
                      Resize(rNAMs.Rows.Count, rNAMs.Columns.Count)
    End With

    With rNAMs
        For rw = .Rows(1).Row To .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
            For cl = .Columns(1).Row To .Columns(.Columns.Count).Row
                If (.Cells(rw, cl).Offset(0, rEXs.Column + (cl - 1) - cl) = vEX And bCS) Or _
                  (LCase(.Cells(rw, cl).Offset(0, rEXs.Column + (cl - 1) - cl)) = LCase(vEX)) Then _
                    str = str & .Cells(rw, cl).Value & delim
            Next cl
        Next rw
    End With

    build_List = Left(str, Len(str) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

In D7 (as per image below) as,

```
=build_List(A:A, B:B, "x")
```

[image: udf_Build_Lists]
                       <sup>Applying the build_Lists UDf to your sample data</sup>

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Mate Juhasz answered the question very nice and simple, but now the answer dissapeared.

Mate wrote:

```
For r = 1 To 20
  If Cells(r, 2) = "X" Then A = A & "; " & Cells(r, 1) Else
Next
```

And for me that solved it perfectly. Now "A" is a string as I wanted. Thank you so much!